# Adjusting Vaadin grid height

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am trying to add multiple Vaadin grids of different sizes inside a VerticalLayout container.

```
public class Overview extends VerticalLayout {

    Grid<DataTable1> grid1 = new Grid<>();

    Grid<DataTable12> grid2 = new Grid<>();

    Grid<DataTable13> grid3 = new Grid<>();
}
```

So far, each grid is taking up an equal amount of vertical space, as shown in the image below.

[grids taking equal vertical space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfdd6.png)

However, I would like to show the grid as shown in the image below where the height gets dynamically adjusted as per the number of rows and cloumns:

[desired grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjD65.png)

Is there any way I can adjust the individual grid height?

So far I have found a way to adjust the row height not the height of the whole grid itself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grid`, like all components that implement `HasSize`, has a method `setHeight()`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might be looking to achieve dynamic height based on the number of rows, which can be done using `setAllRowsVisible(true)`: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#dynamic-height